# Prove $1+2^{1}+2^{2}+\dots+2^{\left(d-1\right)}=\frac{1\left(2^{d}-1\right)}{2-1}=2^{d}-1\ \lt \ n$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, logarithms

> $1+2^{1}+2^{2}+\dots+2^{\left(d-1\right)} < n$ implies
> $d\le\log_{2}\left(n\right).$
>
> $1+2^{1}+2^{2}+\dots+2^{\left(d-1\right)} ≥ n$ implies
> $d>\log_{2}\left(n\right)-1.$
>
> Show that$\quad d = ⌊\log_{2}\left(n\right)⌋.$

Hi, I'm not sure about my solution, specially the part where I substitute "$\ge$" with "$\gt$" and the last proof with the floor.. I feel like I did the wrong direction there and was wondering if it's valid, and if not, how should I approach it?

**A.**

$1+2^{1}+2^{2}+\dots+2^{\left(d-1\right)}=\frac{1\left(2^{d}-1\right)}{2-1}=2^{d}-1\ \lt \ n$

As $(2^{d}-1),n\in N$, we have

$2^{d}-1\lt n\ \ \ \ \implies\ \ \ \ 2^{d}\le n$

$\log_{2}\left(2^{d}\right)\ \le\log_{2}\left(n\right)$

$d\le\log_{2}\left(n\right)$

**B.**

$1+2^{1}+2^{2}+\dots+2^{\left(d-1\right)}=\frac{1\left(2^{d+1}\right)}{2-1}=2^{d+1}-1\ \ge\ n$

As $(2^{d+1}-1),n\in N$, we have

$2^{d+1}-1\ge n\ \ \ \ \implies \ \ \ \ 2^{d+1}\gt n$

$\log_{2}\left(2^{d+1}\right)\ \gt \log_{2}\left(n\right)$

$d+1\gt \log_{2}\left(n\right)$

$d\gt \log_{2}\left(n\right)-1$

**C.**

Let $x\in R$.

$⌊x⌋ =$ max$\{n\in Z | n\le x\}$

Therefore $⌊x⌋\le x$.

Assume toward contradiction $x-1\ge ⌊x⌋$, then $x\ge ⌊x⌋+1\ge ⌊x⌋$

But by the closure of $Z$, $⌊x⌋+1\in Z$ in contradiction to the maximality of $⌊x⌋$.

Therefore $x-1\lt ⌊x⌋\lt x$. Substituting $x = d = \log_{2}\left(n\right)$ we get

$\log_{2}\left(n\right)-1\lt ⌊\log_{2}\left(n\right)⌋\lt \log_{2}\left(n\right)$, as required.

Comment: Please remove the image and use mathjax, at 700 points this is something that newcomers do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the sum is a geometric series we have that $$1+2+2^2+\ldots+2^{d-1}=2^d-1.$$
If we assume that $$2^d-1<n \Longrightarrow 2^d<n+1 \Longleftrightarrow 2^d\leq n \quad \text{(just add $1$ in both sides)}.$$
This last equivalence is a consequence of $n$ belonging in $\mathbb{N}$ and not in $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{N}$. Finally, taking by applying logarithms... $$d<\log_2(n+1)\quad \text{and} \quad d\leq \log_2n.$$
These are two different ways of saying the same thing. The same can be applied to the '$\geq$' part of the statement, and by adding both you can write $d$ as $$d=\lfloor \log_2n \rfloor$$ in a very compact way.